# In Android how to set vector drawable size

Tags: android, vector-graphics

I read about the [Add Multi-Density Vector Graphics](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) and that I only need one vector xml image file to support all screen sizes. However when I try it I still have to set the:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/country_image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp">
```

`android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` like this above code to make the vector have the size I want.

In the above code the `AppCompatImageView` show a vector country flag image and if I don't set the width and height the image take up hole screen.

How is this suppose to work?

Comment: so if you dont want full screen, then what size do you want?

Comment: I hade this png image in hdpi, xhdpi.. folders and now I wanted to test the vector drawable so I only would need one image instead of the hdpi, xhdpi.. I thought that using a vector image would automatically size the drawable

Comment: the problem is view - it is the view that sets the drawable size - so size your view first and the drawable will adjust by itself

Comment: Thanks but if i must set the size of the view  then I need many xml layout files for all different density devices right ?

Comment: Then I could go back to use the hdpi, xhdpi.. folders right?

Comment: why many xml layouts? what size do you want? 50dp x 35dp ? so set it as you already did in your layout xml file

Comment: please show your drawable.xml code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, simply saying, **the vector graphic file contains rules how to draw the image**. And those rules are **independent of the image size**. So you'll use the same vector file for any resolution and any size, that's why you will need only one file.

Secondly, the reason you need the `hdpi`, `xhdpi` and other versions of your png is to display your image on screens with different pixel densities. For examle you won't need a big image to show it on an old phone with **320x480 resolution**. So the **system will pick up your mdpi or ldpi png**. But if your image is shown on a **Full HD screen** for example the small png would look pixelized, so **the system picks `xhdpi` or `xxhdpi` png version**. It can't make `xhdpi` from `ldpi`, so you **need different image files**.

On the other hand, when you use vector graphics **system can create an image with any resolution it wants from the same file**. It will create a small image for 320x480 screen and large image for Full HD screen - so you need **only one file to rule them all**!

Replying to your comment:

You can put your layout.xml file in the `res/drawable` and it will be used for all screens. Then you set the size in dp.

> dp or dip Density-independent Pixels - an abstract unit that is based
>   on the physical density of the screen. These units are relative to a
>   160 dpi screen, so one dp is one pixel on a 160 dpi screen. The ratio
>   of dp-to-pixel will change with the screen density, but not
>   necessarily in direct proportion. Note: The compiler accepts both
>   "dip" and "dp", though "dp" is more consistent with "sp".

So you'll have one layout file, set the `layout_height` and `layout_width` of the image once in it and it will be used on all possible screens.

Comment: Yes exactly so why in my question do I have to set the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` for every resolution when you say it will be be created by the system?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Though I don't understand why do you want to set the size for every resolution. If you use DP it will be actual real-world size, not pixels, so it will be same on any screen. The system will take care of it, based on your one vector drawable file and one layout file.